# Text not centred in TextView on Android when using Gravity CENTER

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to achieve a simple initial, centred in a textview.

Here's my xml and the image it results in:

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/initial_view"
        style="@style/my_style"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="@color/font_white"
        android:textSize="34sp" />
```

Gravity set to center. I also tried setting the gravity programatically.

[image: Text not centered, textview]

Am I missing something or is this an android bug?

Style is:

```
<style name="normal_text">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the layout_width and layout_height to wrap_content? It may be that the fixed bounds of the TextView and the text size are conflicting

Comment: post your `my_style`

Comment: I guess your `my_style` has some paddings...

Comment: my_style has no padding

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

and also try this,

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create an XML file circle.xml in your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@color/black" ></solid>
</shape>
```

and for your TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/initial_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:text="C" />
```

Comment: I have the same thing already... That's how I achieve the circle. Using an oval shape with a fixed height for the text view. Changing the size in the shape doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

For `android:gravity="center"` to work your `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` need to be set to `match_parent` or `fill_parent`.